# How to find out whether I have an original press of an LP?

Tags: the-beatles, vinyl-pressing

My husband recently brought home some vinyls of "A Hard Day's Night" and "The Magical Mystery Tour" yesterday and we've been cruising around sites looking for ways to determine whether they're in fact first press versions, but we're having a tough time definitely proving it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the cat number and then go to [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com).

This data base has a lot of references and is very accurate, especially for famous albums.

For [*A Hard Day's Night*](https://www.discogs.com/The-Beatles-A-Hard-Days-Night/master/24003) for example, the earliest version I could find has the cat number **PMC 1230**, an mono English release from Parlophone in 1964.

[image]